# iPhone: User data saves/loads in simulator, but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

FI can save and load Dictionary data within the simulator but when I run it on my iPhone it doesn't seem to work. I cant quite tell what is happening.  Here is how I save and load data:

Loading

```
NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
NSDictionary *wholeDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@userdata.dat",homeDir]];
```

Saving

```
NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
[dict writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@userdata.dat",homeDir] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSHomeDirectory` returns the application directory, which is not writeable.  You need to write your data to the application's documents directory:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[dict writeToFile:[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userdata.dat"] atomically:YES];
```